# Google Sheet merge using source code

Tags: google-sheets, mail-merge

I am using the below source code which I'm happy with however there are a couple of things I would like to tweak to make my life a little easier.

For the final merged docs I'm wanting to know:

- how you can show an image by referencing a link/URL
- a Google link to a form housed in the Google Drive
- and output as pdf not word
- basic cell formatting like indent + bullet point

---

```
function onOpen() {
     const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
     menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
     menu.addToUi();
    
    }
    
    function createNewGoogleDocs() {
    
    const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('DOCID');
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID')
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() .getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      
    rows.forEach(function(row, index){
     if (index === 0) return;
     if (row[12]) return;
     const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[0]}` , destinationFolder)
     const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
     const body = doc.getBody();
        
     body.replaceText('{{Field1}}', row[0]);
     body.replaceText('{{Field2}}', row[1]);
     body.replaceText('{{Field3}}', row[2]);
       
        
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 3).setValue(url)
        
      })
      
    }
```

If someone can assist me that would be appreciated.